# Changing Font of all Numbers in Main Body, Headings and TOC

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, sectioning

I am writing a thesis and really want to use the font "Nunito".

Unfortunately Nunito has numbers with different heights (old style).
[image: picture of numbers from https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/nunito/]

I do not like those numbers, therefore I would like to change the font, but only of the numbers.

I need the automatic generated numbers in the heading "1 Heading on level 0" and in the table of contents changed as well.

Help would be much appreciated.

An minimal example code is:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{nunito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily} % nunito for headings

\title{Test Things Out 1234567890}
\author{Pen Tagram\\1234567890}
\date{Today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
Here some numbers: 1234567890
Workaround $1234567890$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nunito has both old-style and lining numbers …

Comment: Can you tell me how to access lining numbers in nunito then? That would actually solve my problem completely! :)

Comment: I am using the actual font (with `\fontspec`, not some package), see MWE below. ETA: Or, what @Jinwen said :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `nunito` doesn't have a documentation and in its README only the option `scale` is mentioned. However, if you take a look at `nunito.sty`, you will find the line

```
\DeclareOptionX{lining}{\edef\Nunito@figurestyle{LF}}
```

Thus to use lining number, you can simply import the package with

```
\usepackage[lining]{nunito}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that worked and is exactly what I needed. I tried to find documatation but did not find find or understand the \DeclareOption code. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Compile this document with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Nunito-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}
Have some numbers: 1234567890
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am working with overleaf, therefore I don't know if I can use your suggestion, but the other solution checks out. :)
I can't believe that it's that simple, when I was tying to solve that problem for ages :D

Comment: I think you can choose your engine on Overleaf, too – but whatever works for you. The font has actually tabular (=fixed width) figures, too, should you ever need them.